# How to calculate "leal (%rax, %rcx, 3), %rdx " this kind of stuff?

Tags: assembly, system

Sorry that this is my homework problem, but I just don't know how to calculate.
please help, thank you!

Suppose register %rax holds value 5 and %rcx holds value 10. Fill in the table below with formulas indicating the value that will be stored in register %rdx for each of the given assembly code instructions: (Answer in decimal)

leal (%rax, %rcx, 3), %rdx

leal 0xA (, %rax, 8), %rdx

leal 8 (%rax, %rcx), %rdx

leal (%rax, %rax), %rdx

Comment: Have you tried just writing the code?  Put the value in the registers, use a debugger to execute the instructions and see what ends up where.

Comment: `leal (%rax,%rcx,3),%rdx` is invalid. Also, please consider just reading the manual. Stack Overflow is not a site to have others do your homework.